# Check multiple roles before login

Tags: node.js, express

i have 3 user roles which is guest, member and admin. i want to give permission only for member and admin to login. here my code:

```
//user role middleware
var needsGroup = function(group) {
return [
passport.authenticate('local'),
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user && req.user.role === group)
      next();
    else {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'please subscribe before login');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
  }
]  
};


// Login 
router.post('/login', needsGroup('member', 'admin'), (req, res, next) => {
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
})(req, res, next);
});
```

so my problem here is, only one of these role can login. user with admin role cannot login while member can login. any help?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your middleware variable you only take one parameter `group` where you provide two in your call `needsGroup('member', 'admin')`. The solution would be to make this parameter an array so you can later update the groups without updating the function.

```
//user role middleware
var needsGroup = function(groups) {
return [
passport.authenticate('local'),
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user && groups.indexOf(req.user.role) !== -1)
      next();
    else {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'please subscribe before login');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
  }
]  
};


// Login 
router.post('/login', needsGroup(['member', 'admin']), (req, res, next) => {
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
})(req, res, next);
});
```

The code `groups.indexOf(req.user.role) !== -1` simply checks if the role of the user exists in the array passed(`['member', 'admin']`)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, its work ! 

i already get this done with OR condition on my middleware but  i think your answer is better.

`if ((req.user && req.user.status === 'member') || (req.user && req.user.status === 'admin'))`